# more apples, no more pears

Tags: adverbes

While writing French as I've been speaking it for over a decade, I found myself writing "plus de pommes, plus de poires", - but realised that's utterly ambiguous - which "plus" means more, which means less? So how can I say, or write, "[more apples, no more pears](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=fr&text=more%20apples%2C%20no%20more%20pears&op=translate)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I can't find anything reasonably short for an unambiguous phrase that can stand alone, as on a notice board for instance.

> • des pommes en plus grande quantité, plus du tout de poires

- Elle lui a demandé s'il avait toujours un bon approvisionnement en pommes et en poires et il lui a répondu « j'ai des pommes en plus grande quantité, plus du tout de poires ».

In a sentence this problem does not exist if the formal negation is used consistently, but that is not the case.

- Ils ont plus de pommes et n'ont plus de poires.
- — Est-ce que tu mange toujours des fruits ?
  — Je mange plus de pommes, plus du tout de poires.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents

> plus de pommes ; finies les poires :-)!

Comment: Better to write ***fini** les poires*. With the agreement: "pears have been eaten up to the last one", without the agreement: *C'est fini, les poires*, i.e. "pears won't be served/grown/accepted/... anymore."

Answer (score 1):

Orally, there would be no ambiguity and as written, the context might help understanding the expected meaning.

Otherwise, If you need something unambiguous you might say:

> De plus en plus de pommes, de moins en moins de poires
> Davantage de pommes mais plus aucune poire
> Abondance de pommes, pénurie de poires
> A fond pour les pommes et on oublie les poires !

Dimitris' *[fini(es) les poires](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52597/1109)* is nice too.